# Does Keras convolution option "channels_first" work with Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras-layer

Keras documentation for a Conv2D layer implies that a value of "channels_first" can be used for the parameter data_format, supporting data that is in "NCHW" format, rather than the default "NHWC" format. But this doesn't seem to work in the code below.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

#this works:
data = tf.random.uniform((1,5,5,1))
model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1,(3,3),data_format="channels_last")])
model(data)       

#this doesn't:
data = tf.random.uniform((1,1,5,5))
model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1,(3,3),data_format="channels_first")])
model(data)
```

For the "channels_first" case, I get the message:

```
UnimplementedError: Generic conv implementation only supports NHWC tensor format for now. [Op:Conv2D]
```

Am I making some silly error here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keras is built to work with two backends: Theano and TensorFlow.

Theano uses the "channels_first" format (NCHW) while TensorFlow uses the "channels_last" format (NHWC). As far as I know the "channels_first" format **isn't supported** for the TensorFlow backend.

Comment: It does appear that "channels_first" is actually not supported for Tensorflow, contrary to what you would think from the keras documentation.  It is easy enough to get around the issue - using simple tensorflow.transpose() and/or numpy.moveaxis() logic.  I am surprised that the Keras implementation doesn't trivially convert between 'channels_first' and 'channels_last' behind the scenes to support the former, since it seems that tensorflow.transpose() provides a one-line, seemingly foolproof way to do this.